# Crear un mesaje de aviso al usuario de que el formulario fue enviado correctamente

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo mi pagina web y tengo un problema con el formulario, ya que he creado un `html` y un `js` para setear que le avise si el usuario no llena los campos del mismo, pero no logro agregar el código para que cuando el usuario completo todo, aparezca un mensaje en la misma pagina, como por ejemplo **Su mensaje fue enviado**.

Agrego el código del `html` y `Js` para ver si ustedes me pueden ayudar a hacer esta función. ¿Sería posible?

```
        <!-- Seccion Contacto -->
        <div class="row contacto justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
                <h2 id="tres" class="titulo">Contact</h2>
                <form action="" class="formulario" id="formulario" name ="formulario">
                <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Add your Name/Last Name here....">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Add your email here......">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <textarea name="texto" id="texto" placeholder="Write your question here..."></textarea>

                    <ul class="error" id="error"></ul>

                    <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Send">

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

</footer>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="js/formulario.js"></script>


var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario'),
    nombre = formulario.nombre,
    email = formulario.email,
    texto = formulario.texto,
    error = document.getElementById('error');

function validarNombre(e){
    if(nombre.value == '' || nombre.value == null){
        console.log('Por favor completa el nombre');
        error.style.display = 'block';
        error.innerHTML += '<li>Por favor completa el nombre</li>';

        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        error.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function validarEmail(e){
    if(email.value == '' || email.value == null){
        console.log('Por favor completa tu direccion de email');
        error.style.display = 'block';
        error.innerHTML += '<li>Por favor completa tu direccion de email</li>';

        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        error.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function validarTexto(e){
    if(texto.value == '' || texto.value == null){
        console.log('Por favor completa el texto');
        error.style.display = 'block';
        error.innerHTML += '<li>Por favor completa el texto</li>';

        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        error.style.display = 'none';
    }
}


function validarFormulario(e){
    error.innerHTML = '';

    validarNombre(e);
    validarEmail(e);
    validarTexto(e);


}





formulario.addEventListener('submit', validarFormulario);
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Nos puedes proporcionar el donde envías los datos del formulario?

Comment: @Alejandro Tu pregunta es de `java` o `javascript` ?

Comment: @AlejandroCastan, edita tu pregunta y agrega el codigo javaScript con el que validas el formulario con eso te podemos ayudar mas facil

Comment: FRANCISCO J. BLANCO Es para Javascrip. Ahora adjunto el codigo del archivo Js. Gracias

Comment: Draker. Perdón pero no entiendo bien tu pregunta. El formulario esta en mi web y tiene 3 campos. El primero es para agregar el nombre y apellido, el segundo es su email y el tercero es el pregunta que el usuario nos quiere hacer. Espero haber respondido tu pregunta con eso

Comment: FRANCISCO J. BLANCO. Ya agregue al final el codigo de mi archivo de Javascript. Por ultimo quiere agradecerles a todos su buena voluntad por ayudarme, realmente aprecio eso.....